How can I get a list of tuples which sum to zero for three lists of labelled vectors
list = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, 
  {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0,-1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, 
  {0, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1}};

list2 = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0, 0, -2}}

@Ulrich Neumann  see the source gave the following algorithm which finds the all zero sums (duplication is allowed) where "a" vectors are selected from list and "b" vectors from list2.
slist = Tuples[list, {a}]; 
listb = Tuples[list2, {b}] 
Table[{li, Select[slist, Total[#] == -Total[li] &]}, {li, listb}]

For instance, when a=2, and b=1, one part of the result which the above code gives:
{{{2, 0, 0}}, {{{-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}}, {{-1, -1, 0}, 
  {-1, 1, 0}}, {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}}, {{-1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}}}}

@Bob Hanlon see the source  modified the code  in a way that the code can assign letters to each vectors in the list and list2 and the above result can be  formatted as subscripts  @kglr [see the source]
see the source
improved the code for  removing specific patterns from the lists of tuples which is given by "FF" . The code is given as follows
:
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n];
Format[b[n_]] := Subscript[b, n];

list[1] = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 
    1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 
    1, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, -1, -1} };

list[2] = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 
    0}, {0, 0, -2}};

(repl[#] = 
    Thread[list[#] -> Array[{a, b}[[#]], Length[list[#]]]]) & /@ {1, 2}

sol[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Module[{lista = Subsets[list[1], {m}], 
   listb = Subsets[list[2], {n}]}, 
  Table[{li /. repl[2], 
    Select[lista, Total[#] == -Total[li] &] /. repl[1]}, {li, listb}]]

ClearAll[delete1b, delete2b]

delete1b = 
  MapAt[DeleteCases[
     Alternatives @@ ({OrderlessPatternSequence@##} & @@@ #2)], #, \
{All, 2}] &;

delete2b = 
  DeleteCases[{Alternatives @@ ({OrderlessPatternSequence@##} & @@@ \
#2), {__}}]@# &;
sol[2, 1];

FF = MapAt[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort], {All, 2}]@
   delete1b[sol[2, 1], 
    Alternatives @@   {{a[1], a[4], ___}, {a[2], a[3], ___}, {a[5], 
       a[8], ___}, {a[6], a[7], ___}, {a[9], a[12], ___}, {a[10], 
       a[11], ___}}];

MapAt[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort], {All, 2}]@
  delete2b[FF, 
   Alternatives @@   { {b[2], 
      b[5], ___} } ]  // Column

I would like to ask how we can modify this algorithm if we have a third list, say
list[3] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 
    0, -1}}; 

So that the code finds the all zero sums (duplication is allowed) where "a" vectors are selected from list1 and "b" vectors from list2 and "d" vectors are selected from list3. For instance one answer is {{{-1, -1, 0}}, {{2, 0, 0}}, {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}} where the input needs to be in the format:{{a_4}, {b_1}, {d_4}, d_2}} which is the case one tuple selected from list1, 1 tuple selected from list 2 and 2 tuples selected from list 3.
I managed to update the code until the following part but I cant go further . Can you please help about it?
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n];
Format[b[n_]] := Subscript[b, n];
Format[d[n_]] := Subscript[d, n];

list[1] = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 
    1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 
    1, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, -1, -1} };

list[2] = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 
    0}, {0, 0, -2}};

list[3] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 
    0}, {0, 0, -1}};

(repl[#] = 
    Thread[list[#] -> 
      Array[{a, b, d}[[#]], Length[list[#]]]]) & /@ {1, 2, 3}


Can you please link to the previous question and answers that you are referring to?

Given the complexity, I'm just adding a new, superseding answer to address the question in the comment to my previous answer.
NullVectorSums[counts__Integer][lists__List] := "bad inputs" /; Length[{counts}] != Length[{lists}];
NullVectorSums[counts__Integer][lists__List] :=
  Select[
    Tuples[MapThread[DeleteDuplicates[#, ContainsExactly] & @* OperatorApplied[Tuples], {List /@ {counts}, {lists}}]], 
    ContainsOnly[{0}]@*Apply[Plus]@*MapApply[Plus]];

NullVectorSums[counts__Integer][taggedLists : (_ -> _List) ..] := "bad Inputs" /; Length[{counts}] != Length[Merge[{taggedLists}, Catenate]];
NullVectorSums[counts__Integer][taggedLists : (_ -> _List) ..] :=
  With[
    {indexes = PositionIndex /@ Association[taggedLists]},
    With[
      {displayer = Map[Function[i, Subscript[#1, i]], Flatten[Lookup[Lookup[indexes, #1], #2]]] &},
      Map[
        MapThread[displayer, {Keys[{taggedLists}], #}] &,
        NullVectorSums[counts] @@ Values[{taggedLists}]]]]

The usage pattern here is to provide your own tags. Again, there's a bit of input validation but it's not super robust.
Demonstration:
list[1] = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, -1, -1}};
list[2] = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0, 0, -2}};
list[3] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}};

NullVectorSums[1, 1, 2][a -> list[1], b -> list[2], c -> list[3]] // Column


Update
If OperatorApplied is unavailable in your version, replace this
OperatorApplied[Tuples]

with this
(Tuples[#2, #1] &)

Or, more explicitly replace this
NullVectorSums[counts__Integer][lists__List] :=
  Select[
    Tuples[MapThread[DeleteDuplicates[#, ContainsExactly] & @* OperatorApplied[Tuples], {List /@ {counts}, {lists}}]], 
    ContainsOnly[{0}]@*Apply[Plus]@*MapApply[Plus]];

with this
NullVectorSums[counts__Integer][lists__List] :=
  Select[
    Tuples[MapThread[DeleteDuplicates[#, ContainsExactly] & @* (Tuples[#2, #1] &), {List /@ {counts}, {lists}}]], 
    ContainsOnly[{0}]@*Apply[Plus]@*MapApply[Plus]];

Also, to clarify the usage:
NullVectorSums[0, 1, 2]["mickey" -> list[1], "minnie" -> list[2], "goofy" -> list[3]] // Column


So, you can use whatever tags you want, and you can even exclude a specific input list.

Thank you for your second answer @lericr.  I used mathematica 12 and I copy pasted the code from your second answer together  with the code just under  "Demonstration:"    But the code did not work. It did not give any output .   I appreciate if you may post the whole algorithm in one place.

OperatorApplied was introduced in version 12.1, so if you have version 12.0 that could be the problem. But if you literally saw no output, then there is probably something else going on too. Try starting with a fresh kernel. And provide your exact version.

Thanks for your reply @lericr .  I tried again with a fresh kernel. There is no input.  In the code "OperatorApplied" appears as blue color.  Also a, b and c appears as blue color in "NullVectorSums[1, 1, 2][a -> list[1], b -> list[2],
c -> list[3]] // Column"    I have the version: 12.0.0.0.

a, b, and c should appear blue. That form of the function allows you to specify what "major" term you want used in your subscripted output. If OperatorApplied is blue, then that's the problem. As I said, that function was introduced in version 12.1 and so it won't work with 12.0. I could provide you an alternative if you want.

Thank you for the information @lericr.  I  appreciate  for an alternative

See the update.

Thanks for the update @lericr. I followed your steps. There is no blue color anymore but I still can not get any output.

What do you mean by "not get any output"? If there is literally nothing showing up in an output cell, then you probably have a stray ;. Or the results are empty and and so the Column doesn't display anything. The Column was just there to make the output look nicer--it's not required. Remove it and see what happens. If something is showing up, then provide that. If none of these things help, then maybe there is some other function that isn't working in your version. Or you didn't input the code correctly. Did try literal copy-paste of my code?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

A less brute force idea is to use Solve (although Solve is probably using brute force under the hood). For example:
a = Array["a", 12];
b = Array["b", 6];
c = Array["c", 6];
vars = Join[a, b, c];

sol = Solve[
    And[
        a . list[1] + b . list[2] + c . list[3] == 0,
        {Total[a], Total[b], Total[c]} == {1,1,2},
        VectorLessEqual[{0, vars, 1}]
    ],
    vars,
    Integers
];
sol /. Rule[l_, i_] :> If[i==0, Nothing, l]


{{"a"[12], "b"[3], "c"[2], "c"[6]}, {"a"[12], "b"[2], "c"[3],
"c"[5]}, {"a"[11], "b"[6], "c"[2], "c"[3]}, {"a"[11], "b"[2], "c"[5],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[10], "b"[5], "c"[2], "c"[3]}, {"a"[10], "b"[3], "c"[5],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[9], "b"[6], "c"[3], "c"[5]}, {"a"[9], "b"[5], "c"[2],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[8], "b"[3], "c"[1], "c"[6]}, {"a"[8], "b"[1], "c"[3],
"c"[4]}, {"a"[7], "b"[6], "c"[1], "c"[3]}, {"a"[7], "b"[1], "c"[4],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[6], "b"[4], "c"[1], "c"[3]}, {"a"[6], "b"[3], "c"[4],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[5], "b"[6], "c"[3], "c"[4]}, {"a"[5], "b"[4], "c"[1],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[4], "b"[2], "c"[1], "c"[5]}, {"a"[4], "b"[1], "c"[2],
"c"[4]}, {"a"[3], "b"[5], "c"[1], "c"[2]}, {"a"[3], "b"[1], "c"[4],
"c"[5]}, {"a"[2], "b"[4], "c"[1], "c"[2]}, {"a"[2], "b"[2], "c"[4],
"c"[5]}, {"a"[1], "b"[5], "c"[2], "c"[4]}, {"a"[1], "b"[4], "c"[1], "c"[5]}}

Packaging the idea above as a function:
zeroSums[lists_List, counts_] := With[{n = Length[lists]},
    If[n <= 26,
        zeroSums[AssociationThread[CharacterRange["a", "z"][[;;n]], lists], counts],
        $Failed
    ]
];

zeroSums[lists:{__Rule}, counts_] := zeroSums[Association[lists], counts]

zeroSums[lists_Association, counts_] := Module[{v},
    If[Length[lists] =!= Length[counts], Return[$Failed]];
    v = KeyValueMap[Array, Length/@lists];
    Solve[
        And[
            Total @ MapThread[Dot, {v, Values[lists]}] == 0,
            Total[v, {2}] == counts,
            VectorLessEqual[{0, Join @@ v, 1}]
        ],
        Join @@ v,
        Integers
    ] /. Rule[l_, r_] :> If[r===0, Nothing, l]
]

Example:
zeroSums[{"a"->list[1],"b"->list[2],"c"->list[3]},{1,1,2}]//Sort


{{"a"[1], "b"[4], "c"[1], "c"[5]}, {"a"[1], "b"[5], "c"[2], "c"[4]}, {"a"[2],
"b"[2], "c"[4], "c"[5]}, {"a"[2], "b"[4], "c"[1], "c"[2]}, {"a"[3], "b"[1],
"c"[4], "c"[5]}, {"a"[3], "b"[5], "c"[1], "c"[2]}, {"a"[4], "b"[1], "c"[2],
"c"[4]}, {"a"[4], "b"[2], "c"[1], "c"[5]}, {"a"[5], "b"[4], "c"[1],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[5], "b"[6], "c"[3], "c"[4]}, {"a"[6], "b"[3], "c"[4],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[6], "b"[4], "c"[1], "c"[3]}, {"a"[7], "b"[1], "c"[4],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[7], "b"[6], "c"[1], "c"[3]}, {"a"[8], "b"[1], "c"[3],
"c"[4]}, {"a"[8], "b"[3], "c"[1], "c"[6]}, {"a"[9], "b"[5], "c"[2],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[9], "b"[6], "c"[3], "c"[5]}, {"a"[10], "b"[3], "c"[5],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[10], "b"[5], "c"[2], "c"[3]}, {"a"[11], "b"[2], "c"[5],
"c"[6]}, {"a"[11], "b"[6], "c"[2], "c"[3]}, {"a"[12], "b"[2], "c"[3],
"c"[5]}, {"a"[12], "b"[3], "c"[2], "c"[6]}}


Thanks @Carl Woll
The algorithm gives zero sums but some of these zero sums include also zero sums. How can we exclude these ones. Let me give example:
I run the code for zeroSums[{"a" -> list[1], "b" -> list[2], "c" -> list[3]}, {2, 2,
2}] // Sort.
One answer is {{"a"[1], "a"[4], "b"[1], "b"[4], "c"[1], "c"[4]}.  Here "a"[1]+ "a"[4]=0 , b"[1]+ "b"[4]=0 and "c"[1]+ "c"[4]=0. So  0=0+0+0.  Another answer is "a"[2], "a"[5], "b"[4], "b"[6], "c"[2], "c"[3] and in here "a"[2]+ "a"[5]+ "b"[4]+ "b"[6]+ "c"[2]+ "c"[3]=0 and it does not already include zero sum(s) as the other answer.

I may not understand the problem entirely, but here's my attempt:
(* Just some basic input validation *)
NullVectorSums[counts__Integer][lists__List] := "bad inputs" /; Length[{counts}] != Length[{lists}];
NullVectorSums[counts__Integer][lists__List] :=
  Select[
    Tuples[
      MapThread[DeleteDuplicates[#, ContainsExactly] & @* OperatorApplied[Tuples], {List /@ {counts}, {lists}}]],
    ContainsOnly[{0}]@*Apply[Plus]@*MapApply[Plus]]

So, if we have two lists (of lists), and we want to take two members of the first list (with possible duplication) and one from the second such that those three members (which are lists) sum to a zero vector, then we'd proceed like this:
list[1] = {{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}};
list[2] = {{0, -2, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}};

NullVectorSums[2, 1][list[1], list[2]]
(*
  {{{{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, {{0, -2, 0}}}, 
   {{{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}}, {{-2, 0, 0}}}}
*)

This doesn't quite match the structure of the previous implementations in the other threads, but it's semantically equivalent. Each result is a list of lists. The first list being the items pulled from the first list in the input, the second from the second, etc.
This implementation generalizes to more inputs:
list[1] = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, -1, -1}};
list[2] = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0, 0, -2}};
list[3] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}};

NullVectorSums[1, 1, 2][list[1], list[2], list[3]]
(* 24 solutions found, here is just one example:
   {{{1, 1, 0}}, {{-2, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}}
*)

I haven't stress tested this. We're using Tuples twice, so I'd expect this to get out of hand quickly as the inputs get larger.

Thank you for answer @lericr refering to your answer: {{{1, 1, 0}}, {{-2, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}} can we able to represent it with subscripts: {{a_1}, {b_4}, {d_1, d_4}}
